# Is there a list of supported fonts for Safari Mobile (ie. iPad and iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts, mobile-safari

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of the supported fonts in Safari Mobile for iPad and iPhone. In fact, which fonts can I use in my website?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should try this site: http://iosfonts.com/

it has a table with all supported Fonts for iPhone and iPad

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to have been abandoned since iOS9 :-(