# Default list of fonts which supports android,ios and blackberry operating systems

Tags: android, ios, fonts, blackberry-jde

**Scenario**

We are group of friends whom developing the applications for android, blackberry and ios operating systems, we are in need to implement the font family changes in our application.

What I need:

Is there any common list of fonts which are supported by all three operating systems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316269/is-there-a-list-of-supported-fonts-for-safari-mobile-ie-ipad-and-iphone/7316604#7316604

Answer (score 6):

**iOS:** Here is a list of the default fonts supported on iOS: http://iosfonts.com/

**Android:** There are only three system wide fonts in Android; normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and monospace (Droid Sans Mono). Source: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/List_of_fonts_included_with_each_device

**Blackberry:** http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Adobe-AIR-Development/List-of-available-fonts/td-p/1243913

Comment: the apple link has expired

Comment: apple link replaced

Answer (score 3):

No and yes.

If you have the font you can display any font on Android but default Android only have roboto font.

iOS has at least helvetica family of fonts and I believe it also supports custom fonts (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Edit**:
I believe there is no build in fonts that are supported on all the platforms, BUT all platforms support custom fonts so you should just pick one and use it.

For iOS custom fonts see here: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

For Android custom fonts see here: [Custom Fonts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android)

For Blackberry custom fonts look here: [To set multiple fonts in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309855/to-set-multiple-fonts-in-blackberry)

Hope that clarified a little

Comment: no and yes its confusing,i expect any one answer from you sir,any common fonts which support all three operating systems?you mentioned **roboto** and **helevetica** which cant be supported by blackberry devices,i need atleast four sir

Answer (score -1):

sorry it's not possible  but android and blackberry is supported sans and serif , blackberry and ios support Arial